# ATEX - Infallible Current limiting resistors

Tags: current, current-limiting, hazardous-areas

I'm preparing an intrinsically safe electronic board according to 60079-11.
In this standard film type resistors are accepted as infallible current-limiting resistors, which means that that they fail only to an open circuit.

In my opinion "film type" is quite general. For example, common SMD resistors are thin film type or thick film type.

Because of this, can SMD resistors be considered as infallible current limiting resistors?

Comment: I'm not convinced anything can be considered infallible... esp. SMD parts that can de-solder themselves and move, shorting out the underlying pads.

Comment: What exactly does the standard say?

Comment: Standard says:Current limiting resistor shall beone of the following types:
A) film type
B)... (other type)
C)... (other type)

Comment: The result must be under ignition curves with the safety factor applied. e.g 1.5 x supply voltage

Comment: But what regarding SMD resistor? Can they be considered as Infallible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes thick film SMDs are widely used with intrinsically safe (IS) certified circuits. It would make it impossible otherwise to build the board density required for most modern equipment, including IS certified equipment etc.